# Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

intento recorrer un array de objectos con .map pero me sale un error: Error: Objects are not valid as a react child. 
lo que intento recorrer es esto: [{…}]
0:
id: 0
element:
type: "textarea"
key: null
ref: null
props: {cols: "100", rows: "10"}
_owner: null
_store: {}
**proto**: Object
**proto**: Object
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)

element obtiene el state de la aplicación que sería igual a la parte anterior:

```
const Board = () => {
const element = useSelector(state => state.reducer);
console.log(element)
const dispatch = useDispatch();
return (
    <Div>
        {element.map(el => {
            return <Div key={el.id} id={el.id}>
                {el.element}
                <Button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteElement(el.id), document.getElementById(el.id).remove())}>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                </Button>
            </Div>
        })}
    </Div>
)
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué contiene `el.element`?,ese elemento ahí debería de tener un String o un número, de lo contrario por eso es el error.

Comment: contiene un elemento html